# PyGtk: Scrollist with Entry, can I set an Id

Tags: python, gtk, signals, pygtk, gtkentry

I have a scroll list on my window that I am going to insert 2 entry for each row, I am trying to understand how I can catch the entry that has been changed and update my array with this value.

I will explain what is my code:

I have an array that has 2 fields: Name and Description
Each row has 2 entry, Name and Description
When I am going to modify the row number 2 I want to update my object on my array:

```
rows[1].name = XXX rows[1].description = YYY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to consider using `Gtk.TreeView` with editable cells. The underlying `Gtk.ListStore` could replace your array.

But you can also use your existing entries and pass any data you want as "user data" to the callback for the `"changed"` signal.

```
def on_entry_changed(entry, data):
    print("Row %d, Column %s - %s", data[0], data[1], entry.get_text())

for i in xrange(10):
    name = Gtk.Entry()
    name.connect("changed", on_entry_changed, (i, "name"))
    description = Gtk.Entry()
    description.connect("changed", on_entry_changed, (i, "description"))
    # add your entries to a box or whatever
```

Comment: I found a solution. I created a custom signal that I am going to pass the id of the array.